# Group of orientable symmetries of the 3-dimensional unit cube.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Let $G$ be the group of orientable symmetries of the $3$-dimensional unit cube. Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_4.$

I also got the following hint:

The unit cube has four diagonals that pass through the opposite corners, and $G$ acts on the set of diagonals.

Still, I do not know how to solve this problem. I have the following questions:

1- What is the meaning of orientable symmetry?

2- What is the relation between the action of $G$ and the isomorphism I should find?

Could someone help me answer these questions and solve the problem, please?

**EDIT:**

Do we actually need to know all the rotations of the cube and conclude from them the corresponding permutations of the vertices to write the isomorphism in this question?

Comment: 1. An _orientable symmetry_ is a rotation (i.e., not a reflection). 2. Perhaps show that (a) every rotation of the cube permutes the diagonals, (b) the mapping from rotations to permutations is a homomorphism, and (c) is injective. Then (d) count how many transformations there are of each type to deduce surjectivity.

Comment: Since the cube has six faces, there are six possible orientations that a symmetry can have. Thus, there are 6! possible symmetries of the cube. However, since the cube is symmetric, there are only 24/6 = 4! possible orientations of the cube. Therefore, G is isomorphic to S4. Also In group theory, an orientable symmetry is a symmetry of an object that can be reversed by flipping the object over. This is also known as chiral symmetry.

Comment: Is the reflection symmetry is called non-orientable symmetry?@AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: @AmirrezaHashemi does this chiral symmetry a kind of rotation also?

Comment: I've never heard the terms _orientable_ and _non-orientable_ applied to symmetries, only _orientation-preserving_ and _orientation-reversing_. But if I came across the term _non-orientable symmetry_ out of context in a setting such as this question, one guess would be that it means a _reflection_.

Comment: Color each pair of opposing corners of the cube with the a distinct color. You will get four colors.  Select in a fixed order the $(1,1,1),(1,1,-1),(1,-1,1),(-1,1,1)$ corners of the cube . Their colors are distinct and each orientable symmetry applied to the cube permutes which colors correspond to those corners  in a unique way. The permutations correspond to $S_4$.
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Hemicube.svg/200px-Hemicube.svg.png

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Do we actually need to know all the rotations of the cube and conclude from them the corresponding permutations of the vertices to answer this question?

Comment: @user3257842 Do we actually need to know all the rotations of the cube and conclude from them the corresponding permutations of the vertices to answer this question?

Comment: @AmirrezaHashemi Do we actually need to know all the rotations of the cube and conclude from them the corresponding permutations of the vertices to answer this question?

Comment: Yes, we actually need to know all the rotations of the cube to answer this question. The reason is that the symmetric group $S_4$ is the group of all permutations of the vertices of the cube, and the group of orientable symmetries of the cube is a subgroup of $S_4$. @MathIgnorance

Comment: But the question is asking me to show that it is isomorphic which means that it has the same number of elelments of $S_4 $ ..... Do you know a book that gives us all the rotations of the cube and their corresponding permutations? @AmirrezaHashemi

Comment: There is not a specific book that gives all of the rotations of the cube and their corresponding permutations, but there are a few websites that have this information. For example, the website Speedsolving.com has a list of all of the possible rotations of the cube and their corresponding permutations. @MathIgnorance

Comment: @AmirrezaHashemi I looked at the site you mentioned but I could not specify specifically where is the cube rotations with their corresponding symmetries. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book's hint is to consider the *four diagonals* of the cube (the *long diagonals*, lines passing through a pair of antipodal vertices), which are permuted by every symmetry of the cube, and particularly by every rotation. In the hope a sketch helps:

[image: The four long diagonals of a cube]

Enumerating all the rotations is not necessary, but it might be a good exercise depending on your background and interests. Rotations of the cube can be described, for example, by

- Geometric action as rotation about some axis;
- Effect as a permutation on the set of four diagonals;
- As signed $3 \times 3$ permutation matrices of positive determinant: $3 \times 3$ real matrices whose entries are all $0$, $1$, or $-1$, that have precisely one non-zero entry in each row and each column, and whose determinant is $1$.

With an eye toward minimizing computation, we can show successively that

1. Every rotation of the cube permutes the diagonals (diagonals map to diagonals, and distinct diagonals map to distinct diagonals).
2. The mapping from rotations to permutations is a homomorphism (performing successive rotations effects performing successive permutations on the diagonals).
3. The mapping from rotations to permutations is injective (no non-identity rotation fixes every diagonal).
4. The number of cube rotations is equal to the number of permutations of the set of diagonals.

To count the number of rotations without enumerating possibilities, it helps to think about:

- If we fix a vertex $0$, how many locations are there for the image of $0$ under a rotation of the cube?
- How many rotations fix the vertex $0$ (or any particular vertex)?

Comment: So what is the definition of the function of the isomorphism? and how can I prove that it is 1-1 and Onto?

Comment: The definition is implicit in item 1. It's possible to be explicit by labeling the diagonals $1$ through $4$ and enumerating every rotation symmetry, but not necessary: item 3. shows one-to-one, and item 4. onto (because a 1-1 map between finite sets with the same number of elements is automatically onto).

Comment: I am struggling to write each rotation and the corresponding permutation to it, I will put a bounty of 100 points for this and I hope you add it to your answer so that I can give you the bounty

Comment: To emphasize, it is not necessary (nor is it computationally or conceptually efficient) to write each rotation and the corresponding permutation; it's only necessary to argue that every rotation permutes the diagonals, and to establish items 1.-4. Is any of that turning out to be difficult...?

Comment: By analogy, it's not necessary to write down every permutation on $52$ letters to show there are $52!$ ways to shuffle a deck of playing cards.

Comment: I just will be more comfortable if I see them concretely ..... I know it is not efficient but at least I want to see them on this small problem of $4!$ permutations and then I can believe any larger permutations after this

Comment: In case it's a helpful observation, rotating a cube a quarter turn about an axis through the centers of two opposite faces cyclically permutes the four diagonals, and rotating a half turn about an axis through the midpoints of two opposite edges swaps a pair of diagonals. Those two permutations generate $S_4$. <> Writing out a rotations-to-diagonal permutations correspondence for all $24$ symmetries is only useful for the _writer_, not for the reader: The important information is not the complete dictionary, but the common structural features (which are given in this answer).

Answer (score 3):

(Feel free to skip the next two paragraphs and go to the construction, if you want.)

I will show you how to concretely construct an isomorphism $S_4 \to G$. I assume that by the word concrete, you mean to have the elements of $S_4$ written as permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and the elements of $G$ written as rotation matrices. If this is what you mean, **you should understand the reason you will not find this information in a book**: different labelings of the diagonals with $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and different bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ will give different concrete maps, so there is no concrete map that can be used as a reference. (There is a "standard basis", but there is no standard labeling of the diagonals. After solving your problem, you might like to think about what happens if you use a different labeling of diagonals, or a different basis.) What can be used as a reference is the idea that the permutations of the diagonals correspond exactly to rotations of a cube, so that's in the book.

Many mathematical constructions can only be given in this way, and you should be able to make them concrete whenever you want to. There is nothing fancy here, it's just brute force. If it's difficult, you should ask if you know how to make all the ingredients in the problem concrete. (For example, do you know how to concretely construct rotations? Rotations that send a given point to another? Permutations of a set?)

For the construction: first, orient the cube along the standard axis and center it at the origin. The diagonals are in the directions $[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, -1, 1]$, and let us call them $1, 2, 3, 4$ in that order. Then, name each face by the outward normal vector and list which diagonals each vertex belongs to, running through the vertices in a clockwise order (only the relative order of the vertices matters here):

- $\hat{x}$: $(1, 2, 3, 4)$
- $\hat{y}$: $(1, 3, 4, 2)$
- $\hat{z}$: $(1, 4, 2, 3)$
- $-\hat{x}$: $(1, 4, 3, 2)$
- $-\hat{y}$: $(1, 2, 4, 3)$
- $-\hat{z}$: $(1, 3, 2, 4)$

Next, consider an arbitrary permutation $\pi$ of $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. I'll choose $1 \mapsto 4, 2 \mapsto 1, 3 \mapsto 3, 4 \mapsto 2$, How should the corresponding rotation $R$ transform the faces? We know how the clockwise order of the vertices changes, and that should uniquely tell us which faces are transformed into which other faces. (Note that we can cyclically translate the ordering of the vertices, and it will still correspond to the same face.)

- $R(\hat{x})$: $\pi(1, 2, 3, 4)$ : $(4, 1, 3, 2)$ : $(1, 3, 2, 4)$ : $-\hat{z}$
- $R(\hat{y})$: $\pi(1, 3, 4, 2)$ : $(4, 3, 2, 1)$: $(1, 4, 3, 2)$ : $-\hat{x}$
- $R(\hat{z})$: $\pi(1, 4, 2, 3)$ : $(4, 2, 1, 3)$: $(1, 3, 4, 2)$ : $\hat{y}$.

So we have that the permutation $1 \mapsto 4, 2 \mapsto 1, 3 \mapsto 3, 4 \mapsto 2$ corresponds with the rotation $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

If you draw the setup above, you will be able to find a matrix for the remaining $23$ permutations (and you should do this, if you want to see them concretely). If you have doubts on why this is an isomorphism, consider why you get one, and exactly one, matrix for every permutation following the process above.

Comment: I did not get the directions of the diagonals you mentioned, will you be able to draw them please? or at list say the direction corresponding to each color in the drawing of the first answer please?

Comment: I am guessing that the green is 1, the violet is 2, right?

Comment: Am I looking at the direction of the diagonal from its top or bottom?

Comment: Can we also have a drawing labelling the vertices?

Comment: Can we also have a drawing labelling the faces as well, please ?

Comment: It depends on the choice of coordinate axes. If you take the diagram in Andrew D. Hwang's answer, one possibility is: $\hat{x}$ is the left face, $\hat{y}$ is the right face, $\hat{z}$ is the top face, violet is $1$, green is $2$, dark blue is $3$, light blue is $4$. When you look at $\hat{x}$ (from the outside), the diagonals in clockwise order are light blue, violet, green, dark blue = $4, 1, 2, 3$ = $1, 2, 3, 4$, which is why $\hat{x}$ gets the label $1, 2, 3, 4$, and so on.

Comment: The diagram of Andrew is tilted, so what exactly you mean by left?

Comment: There's two faces that appear to be in the front (nearest the viewer); the left one is the front face that appears on the left side of the screen and the right one is the one on the right side of the screen.

Comment: actually, I just meant describing rotation (say rotation by 90 around diagonal 1) corresponding to permutation say $(12)$ in $S_4$ ...... that is what I meant by describing the function explicitly ...... like in Joseph Gallian 9th edition, pg. 106, rotations of tetrahedron

Comment: Can you help me in that, please?

Comment: The simplest way is to take a cube, mark the vertices on the same diagonal, do the rotation, and see how the vertices change position. If you have some dice you can use that as the cube, or you can make a cube from a cardboard box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140082/discussion-between-qbzvavba-and-mathignorance).